# Mysqli error - data fetch

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having an error message when I am trying to fetch data from my database to display on my website.

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\wb\display.php on line 17

What is the problem?

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user , $db_pass); 
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT* FROM wd_table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Booking Number: " . $row["bookingID"] . "First Name " .         $row["firstName"] . "Last Name : " . $row["lastName"] . "Email: " . $row["email"] . "ID Number : " . $row["idNumber"] . "ID  Type : " . $row["idType"] . "Phone: " . $row["phone"] . "<br>";
    }
}           
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: Specifically - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770072#12770072

Comment: simple; you didn't select a database

Comment: sorry sorry I am still learning php. I will have to check out how to properly write the code. Thanks a lot FRED, i have added the db name and its working now.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-and-select-data-in-php-and-mysql-beginner-guide/